Why does Jeffery Conditionalization switch to belief updating via the law of total probability?
In Bayesian Epistemology, Jeffery Conditionalization is motivated by the simple principle of conditionalization being defined so as to permit only decisive evidence which warrants setting the agent's posterior credences in a proposition and its negation to 0 and 1.
Why does Jeffery Conditionalization try to solve this limitation by switching the basis of belief updating from the conditional probability formula to the law of total probability formula?  I believe it is the law of total probability which opens up the problem of credences depending on the order in which evidence is obtained (here is an example using jelly beans and tricky lighting, although I also find the example and further-linked proof confusing as it seems to call both the proposition that there is a red jelly bean and the reddish appearance of the jelly bean "red").  It seems to me that the definition of conditionalization could simply be relaxed to include partially-decisive posterior credences, and the conditional probability formula would serve just fine without the appended stipulation that evidence must be decisive.
